# A more elegant way to uniformly sample from non-negative integers with a fixed sum

Tags: python, random, combinatorics

Given a positive integer `n`, I would like to randomly output `n` non negative integers that sum to `m` (a positive integer).The output should be presented as a list of integers (not sorted).

My random sample should be uniformly sampled from all lists of `n` non negative integers that sum to `m`.

You can do this using a method inspired by [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)).

```
import random
def random_start(n, m):
    L = ([0]*m+[1]*(n-1))
    random.shuffle(L)
    return [len(item) for item in ''.join(map(str, L)).split("1")]
```

This works but fine but it is very ugly. How can I make this code more elegant?

Comment: Can you show example invocation with values for `n` and `m`?

Comment: n=5, m=8: [0, 2, 0, 4, 2];; n=3, m=7: [2, 2, 3] @Reinderien

Comment: What is an upper bound, and also typical, value of _n_ for your use case?

Comment: Are you sure that your own implementation has a uniform distribution? In my testing, your method is roughly 20 times as likely to produce a 0 than a 49 for m=50.

Comment: @Reinderien it really should be uniform. I will test it as soon as possible.

Answer (score 3):

**Making your current implementation more readable with better naming**. Your current code is
reasonable, but the function and variable naming don't do much to assist with
readability. Better names and a short comment or docstring can help quite a
bit.

```
def random_segments(n_segments, total):
    '''
    Randomly divides TOTAL into segments of size 0 or larger.
    Returns a list of the segment lengths.
    '''
    SEG = '_'
    DIV = '|'
    segments = [SEG] * total
    dividers = [DIV] * (n_segments - 1)
    xs = segments + dividers
    random.shuffle(xs)
    return [len(seg) for seg in ''.join(xs).split(DIV)]
```

**The primary drawbacks of your current implementation**. (1) As noted in
another review, your code does not scale well with respect to `total`: a huge
value for that parameter causes your code to build a very large list of
`segments`. (2) The logic moves from numbers to strings back to numbers: it
would be more straightforward and natural to stay entirely in the realm of
integers.

**Converting your code's intuition into a better implementation: don't build
any segments**. To avoid those problems, just skip the segment-generation.
Instead focus on computing the divider locations and the differences between
adjacent dividers. At least to my eye, this version is both compact
and intuitive. Of course, it won't win a speed race against numpy,
so take that route if you need to handle very large `n_segments`.

```
from random import randint

def random_segments(n_segments, total):
    '''
    Randomly divides TOTAL into segments of size 0 or larger.
    Returns a list of the segment lengths.
    '''
    dividers = sorted(randint(0, total) for _ in range(n_segments - 1))
    z = zip([0] + dividers, dividers + [total])
    return [d2 - d1 for d1, d2 in z]
```

Answer (score 2):

"Elegant" is an intangible, so let's specify:

- Can we make it faster? Yes (a lot!)
- Can we make it stay in the numeric domain instead of a weird venture into strings? Yes!
- Can we code-golf it down to less Python? Only a little, but no one should care. @lukstru demonstrates what this looks like, and whereas it's interesting academically, production code should not be code-golfed.

Aside from the fact that your approach invites string manipulation into an algorithm where it doesn't really fit, it introduces a runtime complexity that is polynomial in `m`, where a proper solution should be O(1) in `m` (i.e. not be slowed down whatsoever by high values of `m`).

You never replied about what typical range of values we would expect for `n`, so let's assume that it can get large. A vetorised Numpy solution could look like the following:

- Generate n uniformly-distributed floating-point values in [0, 1)
- Normalize by their sum
- Round and cast to `int`
- Calculate the rounding error as the difference between the actual and desired sums
- Compensate for the rounding error by incrementing or decrementing a fixed number of values by 1 as appropriate

Or, closer to your original strategy,

- Generate *n - 1* randomised cuts
- Sort them
- Apply a numerical differential

### Suggested

Containing comparative benchmarks.

```py
import math
import random
from collections import defaultdict
from statistics import mean
from timeit import timeit

import numpy as np
from numpy.random import default_rng

rand = default_rng()


def op(n: int, m: int) -> list[int]:
    L = ([0]*m+[1]*(n-1))
    random.shuffle(L)
    return [len(item) for item in ''.join(map(str, L)).split("1")]


def fmc(n_segments, total):
    '''
    Randomly divides TOTAL into segments of size 0 or larger.
    Returns a list of the segment lengths.
    '''
    dividers = sorted(random.randint(0, total) for _ in range(n_segments - 1))
    z = zip([0] + dividers, dividers + [total])
    return [d2 - d1 for d1, d2 in z]


def lukstru_a(n: int, m: int) -> list[int]:
    cuts = sorted([math.floor(random.uniform(0, m)) for _ in range(n - 1)])
    values = []
    lastCut = 0
    for cut in cuts:
        values.append(cut - lastCut)
        lastCut = cut
    values.append(m - lastCut)
    return values


def lukstru_b(amount, totalSum) -> list[int]:
    cuts = [0] + sorted(random.choices(range(totalSum), k=amount - 1)) + [totalSum]
    return [cuts[index + 1] - cuts[index] for index in range(len(cuts) - 1)]


def numpy_sum(n: int, target_sum: int) -> np.ndarray:
    x = rand.random(size=n)
    x = (x * target_sum / x.sum()).round().astype(int)
    delta = x.sum() - target_sum
    if delta > 0:
        pool, = np.nonzero(x > 0)
        change = -1
    elif delta < 0:
        pool = n
        change = 1
    else:
        return x
    change_at = rand.choice(a=pool, size=abs(delta), replace=False)
    x[change_at] += change
    return x


def numpy_diff(n: int, m: int) -> np.ndarray:
    cuts = np.zeros(n + 1)
    cuts[1:-1] = rand.choice(a=m, size=n-1)
    cuts[-1] = m
    cuts.sort()
    return np.diff(cuts)


METHODS = (op, fmc, lukstru_a, lukstru_b, numpy_sum, numpy_diff)


def test() -> None:
    for method in METHODS:
        for n in (1, 5, 10):
            for target_sum in (10, 50, 100):
                result = method(n, target_sum)
                assert sum(result) == target_sum
                assert len(result) == n


def benchmark() -> None:
    times = defaultdict(list)
    for _ in range(10):
        for method in METHODS:
            def run():
                return method(10_000, 50_000)
            t = timeit(run, number=1)
            times[method.__name__].append(t)

    for method, method_times in times.items():
        print(f'{method}: {1e3 * mean(method_times):.1f} ms')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
    benchmark()
```

### Output

```
op: 58.6 ms
fmc: 19.6 ms
lukstru_a: 9.6 ms
lukstru_b: 7.3 ms
numpy_sum: 1.4 ms
numpy_diff: 1.3 ms
```

### Uniformity testing

You ask:

> It’s not clear to me however that your numpy code is sampling uniformly. Is there a simple proof?

For a test run of n=10, m=50 over 30,000 iterations we have

```py
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import default_rng

rand = default_rng()


def rand_sum(n: int, target_sum: int) -> np.ndarray:
    x = rand.random(size=n)
    x = (x * target_sum / x.sum()).round().astype(int)
    delta = x.sum() - target_sum
    if delta > 0:
        pool, = np.nonzero(x > 0)
        change = -1
    elif delta < 0:
        pool = n
        change = 1
    else:
        return x
    change_at = rand.choice(a=pool, size=abs(delta), replace=False)
    x[change_at] += change
    return x


def test_uniform() -> None:
    total = np.zeros((10, 50), dtype=int)
    col_idx = np.arange(50)
    col_comparison = np.broadcast_to(col_idx, total.shape)

    for _ in range(30_000):
        x = rand_sum(n=10, target_sum=50)[:, np.newaxis]
        # total is 10 x 50.
        # Increment at a column equal to the value from x,
        # and at a row equal to the position in x.
        mask = col_comparison == x
        total[mask] += 1

    print(total[:, :20].T)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_uniform()
```

For each of the 10 output positions as columns, each row representing a value starting at 0, output frequencies are:

```
[[1354 1346 1404 1398 1380 1407 1385 1391 1395 1327]
 [2814 2776 2771 2808 2790 2761 2765 2768 2835 2806]
 [2959 3006 2944 2931 3004 3031 3046 2874 2899 2885]
 [2993 3052 2978 3088 3072 3033 3122 3048 3002 2997]
 [3208 3158 3111 3095 3161 3204 3165 3221 3149 3294]
 [3233 3255 3374 3299 3361 3380 3255 3380 3408 3448]
 [3502 3437 3483 3580 3499 3347 3517 3456 3539 3446]
 [3441 3510 3434 3392 3424 3434 3398 3463 3376 3494]
 [2931 2849 2903 2813 2788 2794 2825 2867 2907 2779]
 [1834 1865 1795 1844 1779 1920 1809 1802 1858 1858]
 [ 974  986  979  961  972  910  958  949  920  927]
 [ 432  440  474  429  438  410  464  435  385  422]
 [ 196  185  205  218  190  207  166  188  184  190]
 [  66   84   90   83   75   95   68  100   84   68]
 [  41   27   27   34   43   44   32   34   40   33]
 [  16   17   20   15   15   10   12   15   12   18]
 [   3    5    6    7    7    8    8    7    4    5]
 [   1    2    1    3    2    2    4    0    1    2]
 [   2    0    1    2    0    2    1    0    1    0]
 [   0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    1]]
```

Across *n*, the distributions are equal, but across *m* the distribution is not uniform. However, it's not obvious that you actually care about this, since your original method exhibits much the same non-uniform distribution and is heavily biased toward small numbers; for n=3 m=50:

```
[[367 378 403]
 [400 365 381]
 [363 361 372]
 [353 350 356]
 [380 348 370]
 [349 342 362]
 [308 326 311]
 [333 357 354]
 [301 304 355]
 [317 315 324]
 [292 325 316]
 [302 317 276]
 [307 261 286]
 [298 290 283]
 [269 265 274]
 [254 283 317]
 [254 255 290]
 [242 259 263]
 [242 242 261]
 [245 233 244]
 [251 262 220]
 [204 215 199]
 [240 203 222]
 [216 216 203]
 [209 213 189]
 [189 186 197]
 [211 202 178]
 [183 184 193]
 [172 180 182]
 [187 178 167]
 [163 157 159]
 [163 168 161]
 [155 142 137]
 [134 151 124]
 [141 119 120]
 [113  92 114]
 [107 139 108]
 [118  96  97]
 [ 85 108  90]
 [ 81 101  84]
 [101  85  72]
 [ 89  80  71]
 [ 62  68  72]
 [ 57  62  52]
 [ 39  61  51]
 [ 48  46  46]
 [ 36  36  35]
 [ 30  16  26]
 [ 18  26  20]
 [ 15  21   9]]
```

Comment: I like your criteria for elegance. It’s not clear to me however that your numpy code is sampling uniformly.   Is there a simple proof?

Comment: @graffe It isn't uniform; but does that matter? The original implementation isn't either.

Comment: My implementation really should be as it is just the stars and bars method. I will test it as soon as I can.

Answer (score 1):

This is longer, but more readable, and if you can reduce the loop with syntactic sugar we might even have an elegant solution

```py
import random

def random_start(n, m):
    cuts = sorted([math.floor(random.uniform(0, m)) for _ in range(n - 1)])
    values = []
    lastCut = 0
    for cut in cuts:
        values.append(cut - lastCut)
        lastCut = cut
    values.append(m - lastCut)
    return values
```

EDIT: found a shorter version, it's less readable now though. Seems like you need some space to make the intent clear.

```
import random

def random_start2(amount, totalSum):
    cuts = [0] + sorted(random.choices(range(totalSum), k=amount - 1)) + [totalSum]
    return [cuts[index + 1] - cuts[index] for index in range(len(cuts) - 1)]
```